# How can i dynamically size buttons according to the screen size?

Tags: android, button, size, tablelayout, dynamically-generated

[image]

I have buttons in an tablelayout. I put the buttons dynamically in the table layout here

```
 TableLayout tblHotels=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tblLayout);
        if(hotels != null){
            int index=0;
            for (int i=0; i<(hotels.length/2); i++) {
                TableRow tblRow=new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                tblHotels.addView(tblRow);
                tblRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                for (int j=0;j<2; j++)
                {
                    tblRow.addView(hotels[index]);
                    hotels[index].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0F));
                    hotels[index].setOnClickListener(this);
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
```

But it appears as in the screen I want my buttons in the same width and a little bigger height. How can i do it? My xmlfile is like this right now.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.arzucaki.sherwoodhotels.Hotels"
    android:weightSum="1"
    >


    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tblLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.6"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


    </TableLayout>




</RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: If there are 100(means more) hotels, then table layout will not properly display. It's better to use list/recyclerview/gridview layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go ahead and create the table rows in xml file and define the height of table rows in dimens.xml file:

Here is a sample representation:

```
 <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/table_row_height">

        <TextView
            android:text="Time"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Time"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="2" />
    </TableRow>
```

Add dimens.xml file for all resolutions which you want to support in their respective folders.
E.g. values, values-w820dp, etc.
Just create a new file named as dimens within these folders and declare your value like this:

```
<resources>
<!-- Table Row height -->
<dimen name="table_row_height">16dp</dimen>
```

This value will be higher in another file under values-w820dp based upon your requirement, maybe like this:

```
    <resources>
<!-- Table Row height -->
<dimen name="table_row_height">24dp</dimen>
```

Comment: all buttons are just fill the screen with weight 1. İ just want to know how can i give a speacial height like a percentage of the screen that would run same in all devices with different screen size.

Comment: in that case you need to define those table rows in xml file and provide size dimensions in dimens file corresponding to different resolutions of device like mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi

you can also go ahead and change the match_parent to wrap_content and provide some padding, this way the controls won't occupy complete screen and provide some padding too. But for your requirement that size should vary based upon device resolution, you have to go with dimens file.

Comment: hımmm that makes sense so can you give an example in your answer so i can try and mark your answer as corrent answer.